# How to set selected tabwedgets manually?

Tags: android, tabactivity

Currently I have a TabHost implemented with 3 tabs each containing a separate activity. My question is how can I change my default selected tab . Default selected tabwedget position is 0,
but I want to selecte my tab according to requirment. may be selected tab 1 or 2 or 3 ..when i switch to tabactivity.
  thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 4):

Really?

```
[Tab Object].setCurrentTab(x);
```